# ReferenceError: $ is not defined after updating application from SQL Membership to Asp.net Identity

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

We have changed our application for ASP.NET Identity and for that we have installed packages like Identity Framework and Owin. An earlier application was working as expected but now it is breaking at

```js
$(window).load(function () { $("#loading").fadeOut(2000); })
```

If I comment on this line it is breaking at next place and gives error as 'DevExpress is not defined'. Because of these controls are not getting loaded:

```js
DevExpress.viz.currentTheme("generic.dark");
```

Some part of code is:

```html
<head runat="server">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DXTREME/css/dx.common.css" />
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body, form {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .tooltip-header {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        /*font-size: 16px;*/
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
    }

    #gauge {
        width: 180px;
        height: 180px;
        float: left;
    }
      
    #loading
  {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    /*Change your loading image here*/
    background: url(images/loading-widget-48.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat transparent; 
}        
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DXTREME/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DXTREME/js/dx.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () { $("#loading").fadeOut(2000); })
</script>
```

All the style-sheet and JavaScript files are in-place.

Comment: check the browser console/network tabs ... does the jquery script load? no 404 errors?

Comment: There is no 'Error 404 not found'. There is no such error.

Comment: odd ... `$` should be defined ... is `jQuery` defined - check in the developer tools console if `jQuery` is defined

Comment: I get error as- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in the line jquery-1.7.1.js:3

Comment: `in the line jquery-1.7.1.js` ... but you're loading `DXTREME/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js` !! and earlier you said there were not errors in the console? where is jqueery 1.7.1 even coming from

Comment: We are using user control and web form page is embedded in that. jquery-1.7.1.js reference was used in the user control but since there is no java script code so I removed that. But I still get following errors in the webform                                             
 VM14838 jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' and 
 VM14837 dx.all.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'  and 
 ReferenceError: $ is not defined at 
    $(window).load(function () { $("#loading").fadeOut(2000); })

Comment: `Unexpected token '<'` somewhere a javascript is failing to load and HTML (probably an error page) is being loaded instead of javascript

Comment: Code was working as expected before. We are facing these issues after changed to Asp.net identity from SQL membership.

Comment: `changed to Asp.net identity from SQL membership` - that doesn't make sense to me so .... Jaromanda out

Comment: Add a slash to the start of DEXTREME: `href="/DXTREME/css/dx.common.css"` assuming DXTREME is a folder in the root of the site. I have also found that some things just don't work if jquery is defined at the bottom of the page. I often have to add it to the top. Try it.